# Why I am unable to Sign in using the manually added users in firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am learning firebase authentication. I set my sign-in method to email/password. I manually added some users and have built a sign-in and a signup form.

When I try to sign in with the manually added user details using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` function I get an error as `code: 'auth/user-not-found'`.

When I try to create a new user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`
the new user created is not reflected in the firebase authentication users table.

Here is my code which fires when I click sign up button:

```
const createUserWithEmailAndPasswordHandler = (email, password) => {

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)        
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

My firebase version: `"firebase": "^7.14.2"`

Please guide me on why the user table is not updating and why I cannot sign in using the manually added user data.

Comment: Show us the code the doesn't let you create a new user.

Comment: Please do share your code and also specify your Firebase version (the provided snippet seems to be V8). Also try adding a catch and see if you get any error like: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => console.log("created")).catch((e) => console.log(e))`. And check the logs

Comment: @Alex Mamo, I would like to clarify that the user is being created but it is not showing in the firebase authentication user table

Comment: Then how do you know is created? If not in the Console, where do you see that?

Comment: @Alex Mamo, In the promise I have done ``console.log(user)``. This shows the created user data in the chrome developer tool console, but when I go and refresh the firebase authentication user table I am unable to see that user in the table